# How do i write from textBox the text to text file and read back from the file to the textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

This is what i did in the top of Form1:

```
string line;
StreamWriter w;
StreamReader sr;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
if (File.Exists(@"d:\test.txt"))
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\test.txt");
                line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                textBox3.Text = line;
                sr.Close();
                sr.Dispose();
            }
            w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt");
```

Then in textBox3 Text Changed event:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (w == null)
            {
                w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\ircbotsettings.txt");
                w.Write(line);
                w.Write(textBox3.Text);
            }
        }
```

Then in Form1 Closing event and also in a button click event i added in both places:

```
w.Close();
w.Dispose();
```

In the textBox text changed event im trying to open/create the file again for writing first writing the line if any string in it then write the new text from the textBox.

The problem is when im running now the program its going automatic first to the textBox3 text changed event and throw an exception on the line:

```
w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\ircbotsettings.txt");
```

The process cannot access the file 'd:\ircbotsettings.txt' because it is being used by another process

What i want to do is:

When typing any text in the textBox in realtime it will save it to the text file.
When i exit the program and run it again read/load from the text file the text and add/put it in the textBox.

So the text file should contain each time only one string and each time when im running the program it should read/load the string back to the textBox.

Comment: Write content to a file in real time is really a bad idea. We normally write periodically with some changed chunk of data.

Comment: Every time text change you reopen the file in the event handler, but not close / dispoe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a StreamWriter or StreamReader, too much clutter and boilerplate.

I would suggest

```
   txtSettings.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path_to_file);
```

and on the Leave or Validated event from the textbox

```
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path_to_file, txtSettings.Text);
```

Don't write to a file on each TextChanged event, or it will write to the file on each keystroke which would prove to be a major bottleneck. Either write to the file on Leave or (Form_Closed if it's in a dialog) or use a Timer to periodically save to the file (and keep track of changes with a boolean that you set to true in the TextChanged event).